# how to set image in top left corner position in linearlayout?

Tags: android

how to set image in top left corner position in linearlayout ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `android:layout_gravity="left|top"` on your `ImageView` in the `LinearLayout`. Also, it will need to be the first child of the `LinearLayout`. Usually, for these sorts of positioning rules, `RelativeLayout` is a better choice.